# Notification not insistent though flag set to insistent in my Android application

Tags: notifications

I am creating a notification as a consequence of an event. The notification code does work but 
i just get a single beep sound not a continuous ringing.
I have set the notification flag to be 'insistent'. But still i do not get continuous sound.
I have searched a lot but could not get solution.
Here is my code

```
 **notification.flags = notification.flags |Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
   notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
  notification.vibrate = new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000};
  NotificationManager manager =  
               (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                      manager.notify(1, notification);**
```

I would like to know if any thing is wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To play the selected mp3 file repeatedly until user open the notification....!

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("http://www.robtowns.com/music/blind_willie.mp3");
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
```

Its solved my problem.. i hope its may solve your problem too.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html">create Notification

Comment: Ya thanks...will surely try...thanks a lot for your reply...i really needed it

Comment: I am using the default notification sound to alert the user.

Comment: I used notification.sound = Uri.parse(RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION).getPath()); as you suggested for mp3. This is not giving me the expected result. Still unable to figure ou the problem

Comment: FLAG_INSISTENT is not working in Oreo above.can you please suggest something?